# In a long sum, how can we find how many terms are preceded by the plus (or minus) sign

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a module that computes a very long expression. I need to count the number of terms in the expression and how many are preceded by a minus sign.

Example: in a + b*c - e + df - g*h we have 5 terms and two are preceded by a minus sign.

I was looking at the Cases command but I could not find any similar examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generalizing a bit to expressions whose coefficients are not just `±1`, one has the following:

```
expr = a + bc - 2 e + 3 df - gh;
Length@expr
Count[expr, _?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ]
(*
  5
  2
*)

Count[expr, _?Negative * Optional[__]]
(*  2  *)
```

They are not strictly equivalent.  `` Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ `` is true if the term is typeset with a minus sign.  The following shows the difference:

```
expr2 = Cos[1] x y + Cos[3] y;
Count[expr2, _?Negative * Optional[__]]
Count[expr2, _?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ]
(*
  1
  0
*)
```

The use of `Optional[__]` is in case there is a term that is simply a number and not a product of a number and an expression (note that `y-x` is `Plus[Times[-1, x], y]` internally):

```
expr3 = expr - 3
Count[expr3, _?Negative*Optional[__]]
Count[expr3, _?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ]
(*
  -3 + a + bc + 3 df - 2 e - gh
  3
  3
*)
```

Answer (score 6):

If your expression is a sum, as in your example, you can do the following:

```
expr = a + bc - e + df - gh
```

make a list:

```
lexpr = List @@ expr
```

Count the expressions with a preceding minus sign

```
Count[lexpr, -x_]
(* 2 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = a + bc - 2 e + 3 df - gh + Sin[ij] - Cos[klm];

neg = Length @ Select[CoefficientRules @ expr, #[[2]] < 0 &]
pos = Length @ expr - neg
```

> 3
>
> 4

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = a + bc - e + df - gh
If[StringMatchQ[ToString@#, "-" ~~ ___], "-", "+"] & /@ 
  List @@ expr // Tally
```

> {{"+", 3}, {"-", 2}}

note this breaks if you have ratios within terms, eg `expr = a - b/c` the `-b/c` becomes `Times[-1, b, Power[c, -1]]` and appears to not have a lead `-`.  Some of the other answers have the same issue, (  I didn't try all.. )