# How to make Solve[] yield only real positive values?

Tags: equation-solving

*I know there may be duplicates, But I have not found any question with a concrete answer for the case I am treating.*

If I have a determinant:

```
Det[f[x]]==0
```

And I want to solve it for x:

```
Solve[Det[f[x]]==0,x]
```

In general, there may be real negative roots, and also imaginary roots.

**Question:** How can I make Mathematica give me only the real and positive roots of the solution?

---

**Attemp:** I tried using `Assumptions` but it seems to only work for assuming constants under derivatives. Also I tried with:

```
Refine[Solve[Det[f[x]]==0,x],x>0]
```

but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

E.g.

```
f[x_] := {{2 + x, x^2}, {1 + x, x^3 - 2}}
Det[f[x]]
```

> -4 - 2 x - x^2 + x^3 + x^4

All roots are

```
NSolve[Det[f[x]] == 0, x]
```

> {{x -> -1.70528}, {x -> -0.422555 - 1.15516 I}, {x -> -0.422555 + 
>       1.15516 I}, {x -> 1.55039}}

Real and positive:

```
NSolve[Det[f[x]] == 0 && x > 0, x]
```

> {{x -> 1.55039}}

Comment: `Solve[Det[f[x]] == 0 && x > 0, x]` works as well, though it gives the answer as a root object. take N[ ] to find the numerical value.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. The other question I have is if I can do that but given some constat $a$ for example. How can Mathematica know that I am defining a positive real value? I tried using Refine[], but I don't know if I am applying it right because it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: What I am trying to say is: given a solution {{x->a},{x->-a}}, discard the negative value of x.

Comment: That is a different issue. See, e.g., [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128860/in-a-long-sum-how-can-we-find-how-many-terms-are-preceded-by-the-plus-or-minus).